# Approximation of delta function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I learned that a sequence of "tent shaped" functions $f_n$(that look like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) compactly supported on $[-1/n,1/n]$ with area equal to 1 converges to the delta function in the sense of distributions.

If I consider a sequence of scaled one-sided tent function $h_n = 2 f_n \chi_{(0,1/n)}$ so that $\int_R h_n = \int_{(0,1/n)} h = 1$, then does this sequence $\{h_n\}$ also converge to a delta function?

Comment: I think you are perhaps proposing a family of *discontinuous* functions, where the "tent shaped" functions mentioned are continuous (and piecewise linear).  This changes the "sense of distributions" for which we would say they converge "to the delta function".

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I am indeed proposing a sequence of discontinuous functions. How does it change the "sense of distributions"?

Comment: Are you sure you defined everything correctly? A tent function on $[-n,n]$ is "spreading out", not "concentrating", so it does not converge to a delta function. Presumably you meant $[-1/n,1/n]$ or similar. Anyway, hardmath's statement has to do with the fact that the meaning of a distribution depends on the space of test functions under consideration. One could look at test functions compactly supported on $(0,\infty)$; then your distributional limit is $0$. One could also look at restrictions of test functions compactly supported on the whole line; then you do get the Dirac delta.

Comment: @Ian My apologies. I meant $1/n$. typos fixed

Comment: @Ian In case where one looks test functions compactly supported on the whole line, why do I need to consider their restrictions? my functions $h_n$ are defined on the whole line

Comment: Ultimately it's the same, the multiplication by zero gives you the same result either way. You just have to be careful about the possibility of your test functions having a discontinuity at zero because this version of the Dirac delta is actually giving you the right hand limit at zero, not the actual value at zero.

Comment: @Ian, in distribution theory the test functions are continuous.

Comment: @md2perpe Traditionally yes, but people use this stuff in less-than-rigorous fashion quite frequently, and so these kinds of caveats should be pointed out unless you're certain everything is clear. In particular in this case there is a subtlety because a function can be discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and continuous on $[0,\infty)$; this particular form of nascent delta function sees such a function as if it were only defined on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $h_n \in L^1_{\text {loc}} $ are such that

1. $h_n \geq 0$
2. $\int h_n (x) \, dx = 1$
3. $\int x h_n (x) \, dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty $

Then $h_n \to \delta $.

**Proof**

First notice that
$$|\phi (x) - \phi (0)| = |\int_0^x \phi'(t) \, dt|
\leq \int_0^x |\phi'(t)| \, dt
\leq \int_0^x \|\phi'\| \, dt
= \|\phi'\| x $$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is uniform/infinity norm.

Then notice that
$$\langle \delta, \phi \rangle = \phi (0)
= \phi (0) \int h_n (x) \, dx
= \int h_n (x) \, \phi (0) \, dx $$

Therefore,
$$|\langle h_n, \phi \rangle - \langle \delta, \phi \rangle|
= | \int h_n (x) \, \phi (x) \, dx - \int h_n (x) \, \phi (0) \, dx|
\leq \int h_n (x) |\phi (x) - \phi (0)| \, dx \\
\leq \int h_n (x) \, \|\phi'\| x \, dx
= \|\phi'\| \int x h_n (x) \, dx
\to 0$$
since $\|\phi'\| < \infty $.

Thus, $h_n \to \delta $ as $n \to \infty $.

You can easily show that "your" $h_n $ satisfy the criteria and therefore approximate $\delta $.

Comment: I don't think the first inequality is right, since $x$ can be negative.

Comment: @AndrewYuan. You are right. It shouldn't be a big thing to fix it, though.